# Uses of writing Lexers and Parsers other than for Compilers?

Tags: regex, parsing, lexer

What kind of problems other than writing compilers can be solved using Lexers and Parsers ?

What are the advantages / disadvantages of using Lexers and Parsers over just writing regular expression statements in a programming language.

Are there any situations where only a Lexer or only a Parser is used ?

PS: Precise Comparison Examples would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lexers and parsers are good for computerized interpretation of anything that is a [context-free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) but not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

In more practical terms, this means that they're good for interpreting anything that has a defined *structure* but is beyond the capabilities of (or more difficult to do with) regex.

For instance, it is [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) if not [impossible](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) to write a regular expression which will determine if a given document is valid HTML (due to things like tag nesting, escape characters, required attributes, et cetera). On the other hand, it's (relatively) trivial to write a parser for HTML.

Similarly, you would probably not want to even try to write a regex to determine the order of operations in a mathematical expression. On the other hand, a parser can do it easily.

---

As for your question regarding individual lexers or parsers:

Neither is "necessary" for the other, or at all.

For instance, one could have human-readable words which translate directly to machine opcodes that would get lexed directly into machine code (this would essentially be a very basic "assembly language"). This would not require a parser.

One could also simply write programs in a way that already was expressed in machine-readable individual symbols and thus easy for a machine to parse - for instance, boolean algebra expressions that used only the symbols `0`, `1`, `&`, `|`, `~`, `(`, and `)`. This would not require a lexer.

Or you could do without either - for instance, [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) needs neither lexing nor parsing because it is simply a set of ordered instructions; the interpreter just maps symbols to things to do. Machine opcodes, similarly, do not require either.

Mostly, lexers and parsers are written to make things *nicer* and *easier*. It's *nicer* not to have to write everything in individual single-meaning glyphs. It's *easier* to be able to write out complex expressions in whatever way is convenient (say, with parentheses, `(3+4)*2`) than it is to force ourselves to write them in ways that machines work (say, [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation): `3 4 + 2 *`).

Answer (score 0):

A famous example where parsing is more adapted than regular expressions (because [the object of processing is, inherently, a non-regular context-free language](http://redsymbol.net/articles/svg-markup-chomsky/)) is X?(HT)?ML manipulation. See Jeff Atwood's [famous blog post on the subject](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html), derived from [a famous answer on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).